# accepts_nested_attributes_fields not showing for join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I have the following tables

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies, through: :companies_regions
  has_many :companies_regions, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :regions, through: :companies_regions
  has_many :product_type, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :companies_regions, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies_regions, :allow_destroy => true
end

class CompaniesRegion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :region
end
```

I want to create a new company and i want to be able to add a new region accordingly to the CompaniesRegion table.

form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(['admin', @company]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :name %>
  </div>
  <div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h4>Basic Coverages</h4>
      <div class="row form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1">#</label>
        <label class="col-md-3">Coverage</label>
        <label class="col-md-1">Description</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :companies_regions do |company_region| %>
          <%= render 'company_region', f: company_region  %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'New Region', f, :companies_regions, partial: 'company_region' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

_company_region.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields form-group row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%#= f.select :region_id, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Region' %>
    <%= f.input_field :region_id, collection: ['Asia', 'America'], class: 'form-control', prompt: 'Please Select' %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <%= link_to_remove_association(f, title: 'Remove') do  %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem here is that when i click the New Region link, i am expecting it to display the details in the _company_region.html.erb but unfortunately it doesnt.

Nothing shows. It doesnt display any data. It however refreshes the page which is absurd.

Dont know if it is because my table is a join table hence the problem or if there is something else that i am missing but based on documentation, this should be fine and should work.

Any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: Please include the _company_region partial in the question. `partial:` is needed because the partial does not follow the naming convention (company_region_fields)

Answer (score 0):

Its a very common misconception that you need to use nested attributes to set assocations. You don't. Rails generates a `regions_ids=` setter for the association that can be hooked up with checkboxes or a select tag.

All you really need with SimpleForm is:

```
<%= f.association :regions %>
```

See the docs for [ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) and associations in [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations) for more details on how this works.

```
<%= simple_form_for(['admin', @company]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :name %>
  </div>
  <div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h4>Basic Coverages</h4>
      <div class="row form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1">#</label>
        <label class="col-md-3">Coverage</label>
        <label class="col-md-1">Description</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.association :regions %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The only reason you would need to use nested attributes is if the user must be able to create regions in the same request. But usually its better to use ajax to handle those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. The behaviour you describe seems to indicate that the `cocoon.js` code is not included/loaded correctly? Did you

- add `require 'cocoon'` in `application.js` ?
- did you include `application.js` in your html?